# Chaning alpha of menubar programmatically in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I am trying to make a hover menu bar.

Below is the code

```
<mx:MenuBar id="mainMenuBar0" x="5" y="250" width="243" height="40" alpha=".2"
                chromeColor="#a8c6ee" cornerRadius="8" buttonMode="true" mouseOut="mainMenuBar_mouseOverHandler(event)" mouseOver="mainMenuBar_mouseOverHandler(event)">




protected function mainMenuBar_mouseOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                if (event.type == MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER)
                {
                       event.target.setStyle("alpha", .8);
                } 
                else 
                {
                      event.target.setStyle("alpha", .2);
                                }

            }
```

The problem is, alpha is not changing. Can anyone guide me what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alpha is not a style it is a property, please try again.  event.target.alpha = .8